# Error while using generate_series in createNativeQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

The Query on executing in PostgreSQL Database is fetching the records properly. But, when implemented using createnativeQuery, I am getting Error

`ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:131 - ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"`

Query Executed successfully in Postgres Database is mentioned below

```
    select d.dt::date as date_current, 
   coalesce(underwriter_daily_cap, daily_file_cap) as file_cap, 
   user_id 
   from generate_series(date '2019-04-05', date '2019-04-09', interval '1' 
   day) as d(dt)  
     left join (
         select upd.*, ud.daily_file_cap
          from mod_underwriter_daily_file_count upd 
           join lsa_assignment_details ud on ud.user_id = upd.user_id
          where ud.user_id = 350 
         ) upd on upd.date_current = d.dt::date
          ORDER BY d.dt DESC;
```

**DAO Layer code is as follows**

```
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public List<Object[]> getUnderWriterCap(String dynamicUserId) {
    log.info("Entered UserSkillMappingHibDAO : 
        getUnderWriterCap");
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Date currentDateMinusFive = 
       DateUtil.getLastFiveDayOldPSTDate();
    Date currentDate = DateUtil.getCurrentPSTDate();

    String queryString = " select  d.dt::date as date_current, 
       coalesce(underwriter_daily_cap, daily_file_cap) as file_cap, user_id  " 
                        +" from generate_series ( date '"+DateUtil.getDateFormat(currentDateMinusFive)+"', date '"+DateUtil.getDateFormat(currentDate)+"', INTERVAL '1' DAY ) as d(dt) "  
                        +" left join ( select upd.*, ud.daily_file_cap from mod_underwriter_daily_file_count upd "
                        +" join lsa_assignment_details ud on ud.user_id = upd.user_id  where ud.user_id =  "+ dynamicUserId
                        +") upd on upd.date_current = d.dt::date  ORDER BY d.dt DESC " ; 

            List<Object[]> records = session.createNativeQuery(queryString)
                        .getResultList();

            return records;  

  }
```

The Exception got in console while executing the above code is as below

Hibernate:  select  d.dt:date as date_current, coalesce(underwriter_daily_cap, daily_file_cap) as file_cap, user_id   from generate_series ( date '2019-04-04', date '2019-04-09', INTERVAL '1' DAY ) as d(dt)  left join ( select upd.*, ud.daily_file_cap from mod_underwriter_daily_file_count upd  join lsa_assignment_details ud on ud.user_id = upd.user_id  where ud.user_id =  403) upd on upd.date_current = d.dt:date  ORDER BY d.dt DESC 
2019-04-09 18:58 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:131 - ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
  Position: 14

Comment: What is the block of text in the middle (between the two large code blocks)? If it's an error trace, it should be formatted as such.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in this. More important than the syntax error is how you're appending a parameter as a string literal.

Instead of:

```
session.createNativeQuery("select * from tbl where param = '" + value + "'");
```

You have to use prepared statements (that is the term to look-up). This is extremely important for security.

```
Query q = session.createNativeQuery("select * from tbl where param = :par1");
q.setParameter("par1", value);
```

Now as for the syntax error, it's caused by your use of PostgreSQL's custom typecast syntax. You have to replace it with the standard SQL typecast from `d.dt::date` to `cast(d.dt as date)`, because Hibernate expects `:` to be the start of a named parameter.

```
String queryString = "select cast(d.dt as date) as date_current, "
                    +" coalesce(underwriter_daily_cap, daily_file_cap) as file_cap, user_id  " 
                    +" from generate_series ( current_date - 5, current_date, INTERVAL '1' DAY ) as d(dt) "  
                    +" left join ( select upd.*, ud.daily_file_cap from mod_underwriter_daily_file_count upd "
                    +" join lsa_assignment_details ud on ud.user_id = upd.user_id  where ud.user_id = :dynuid ) upd on upd.date_current = cast(d.dt as date) ORDER BY d.dt DESC " ; 

List<Object[]> records = session.createNativeQuery(queryString)
                    .setParameter("dynuid", dynamicUserId)
                    .getResultList();
```

I also replaced you current date java calculations with database functions. Instead of doing:

```
Date currentDateMinusFive = DateUtil.getLastFiveDayOldPSTDate();
Date currentDate = DateUtil.getCurrentPSTDate();
...
.setParameter("ds", DateUtil.getDateFormat(currentDateMinusFive))
.setParameter("de", DateUtil.getDateFormat(currentDate))
```

You have the database do it for you using `current_date - 5` and `current_date`.

Another thing you should watch-out for, since your DateUtil is using the old `java.util.Date` class and related stuff is that if you are using a `SimpleDateFormatter` to format it, then it must be a new instance on every call. Do not optimize it to a static final, because it's not thread-safe. I've suffered from this.

edit: I also believe your query can be optimized much further into this, and it will have the same results:

```
select upd.date_current, underwriter_daily_cap, daily_file_cap from mod_underwriter_daily_file_count upd
 join lsa_assignment_details ud on ud.user_id = upd.user_id
 where ud.user_id = :dynuid and
 upd.date_current between current_date - 5 and current_date
 ORDER BY d.dt DESC
```

Notice I removed some fields from the select, like user_id, because you are already telling the database which one you want. The one major difference is this query will skip results for days with no entries.

Comment: Hi, The query mentioned by you in the first solution is working partially. i.e, two things are pending. 1. Not getting the values from lsa_assignment_details table for *non-matched* records. 2. user_id is null in all records.

Comment: The query in the first solution is your query, but with parameter safety. The `lsa_assignment_details` and `mod_underwriter_daily_file_count` are together left-joined to the results from your `generate_series`. If there is nothing there, they are null. I don't know enough about your data structure to help further. You should try splitting it into less-complex queries to verify your results.